# R leaflet, markers color from non variable data

Tags: r, leaflet, mapping, markers

Hello i am a beginner with R. I want to create a map with markers that show the positon of the customers of an entreprise. In my data i have 23 columns with differents informations on the customers.

I have a column "type.de.compte" with 2 non numerical variable that are : optician and ophthalmologist.

And what i m struggling with is to have 2 different colors for my markers , red if the custumer is an optician and blue if he is an opthalmologist.

Might be a silly question but i m struggling with that ..

Here is what i have for now :

```
icons1 <- awesomeIcons(
  icon = 'ion-ios-body',
  iconColor = 'black',
  library = 'ion',
  markerColor = "blue")

 leaflet(data = origAddress) %>% addTiles() %>%
   addAwesomeMarkers(~long,~lat,
                icon=icons1,
                popup=paste(origAddress$Nom.du.compte,
                            "Ville :"origAddress$Ville,
                            "Téléphone:"origAddress$Téléphone.principal))
```

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the following named vector in advance:

```
customer_colors = c("optician"='red',
                  "opthalmologist"='blue')

# optionally, for any exceptions:
colors[is.na(colors)]="white"
```

Then you can use the following code, assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
colors = customer_colors[df$type.de.compte]

icons1 <- awesomeIcons(
  icon = 'ion-ios-body',
  iconColor = 'black',
  library = 'ion',
  markerColor = unname(colors))
```

Hope this helps!